# displaying notifications from onprogressUpdate method from asynctask class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, notifications

i am trying to send a notifications from the on progressupdate method from the asynctack class. Since i am a newbie to android, i don't know where seem to be the error. The AllSensorData is a separate java clas. It would be great if you could help. thanks

Here's my code for the asyntack class

```html
public class AllSensorData extends AsyncTask<String, byte[], String>{
 
 TextView temp,humi,motion,smoke,flame,water,reed,data;
    int notificationID = 1;
 NotificationManager notificationManager =null;
 Context context;
 
  public AllSensorData(TextView temp,TextView humi,TextView motion,TextView smoke,TextView flame,TextView water,TextView reed) {
    this.temp=temp;
    this.humi=humi;
    this.motion=motion;
    this.smoke=smoke;
    this.flame=flame;
    this.water=water;
    this.reed=reed;
   
   }
 
  
  InputStream nis;
  OutputStream nos;
  BufferedReader in;
  DefaultHttpClient httpclient =new DefaultHttpClient();
  URL url;
  URLConnection urlconn=null;
  InputStreamReader isn;


 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpResponse response;
         try {
       while(true){//while connected
      HttpGet httpget =new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.177/");
      response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
      in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

           String msgFromServer = in.readLine();//read the lines coming from the socket
           byte[] theByteArray = msgFromServer.getBytes();//store the bytes in an array
           publishProgress(theByteArray);//update the publishProgress
          
                 
                 if(isCancelled()){
            break;
           }
             }
          

         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             
         } catch (IOException e) {
             
         }
  return null;
 }
  protected void onProgressUpdate(byte[]... values) {
   super.onProgressUpdate(values);
         String command=new String(values[0]);//get the String from the recieved bytes
         String[] parts= command.split(",");
         String part1=parts[0];
         String part2=parts[1];
         
         temp.setText(part1);
         humi.setText(part2);
         
         if(Integer.parseInt(part2)>70)
         {
         NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.context);
    builder.setContentTitle("AM Home Automation");
    builder.setContentText("humidity > 70");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setTicker("alert");
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    //builder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R));
    
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, builder.build());
    notificationID++;
         }
        
         
      
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: the application is not starting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i was going through the code, I dont think that context is initialized properly although it has been declared in the class. Could you cross check that it has beeen initialized before it is used anywhere in the class ( specially in notification builder)

try making the following change in the class

```
public AllSensorData(TextView temp,TextView humi,TextView motion,TextView smoke,TextView flame,TextView water,TextView reed, Context context) {
                this.temp=temp;
                this.humi=humi;
                this.motion=motion;
                this.smoke=smoke;
                this.flame=flame;
                this.water=water;
                this.reed=reed;
                this.context=context
            }
```

Also, remember to pass application context when you initialize this class as follows from your main activity:

`AllSensorData mSensorData = new AllSensorData(temp, humi, motion, smoke, flame, water,reed,getApplicationContext());`

That might just solve your problem!

Comment: man you are a savior :D .. that was the problem.. thanks a lot man,, was struggling for  days with this